# using commands: ">" and "<" to read/ write file

Tags: java, file-io, command, piping

I have a method that reads a file called `personDataBase` using `args[0]` with the command:
`java names/Sort personDataBase`

this is the method:

```
public static Person[] read(String s){
    String readPeople = IO.readFile(s);
    String[] people = readPeople.split("\n");
    Person[] personArray = new Person[people.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
        String person = people[i];
        String[] splitArray = person.split("\\s+");
        personArray[i] = new Person(splitArray[0], splitArray[1],
                                    splitArray[2]);
    }

    return personArray;
}
```

I have to change this so that it works with the command:

`java names/Sort -h -stats < personDataBase`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Am I missing it?  What are you attempting to do with the < or >?

Answer (score 1):

< and > are for standard input and standard output,
it wont work with commandline input

so change your code to take standard input

ex: read the System.in using a buffered reader